# Select all non-digit characters except single dot and single dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a regex in JavaScript that will select all non-digit characters except a single dot and a single dash. I tried `[^0-9\.\-]+` but it doesn't select multiple dots or dashes. So it should select `..` but not `.`

My use case is numeric input validation. A user can type any digit or single dot or single dash. And I will replace invalid inputs with an empty string.

Comment: could you post examples of input with matched substrings?

Comment: Your description is unclear. How would you use such a regex? (Is this an XY problem?)

Comment: Does that mean `-.-` is valid input but `--` is not?

Comment: @melpomene, you're right, `-.-` should be also invalid. It adds complexity :)

Comment: So you really just want to make sure that the input is a valid integer or float, which means a single dot or dash should also be invalid? If so, I wouldn't bother with a regex. Just use `parseFloat(input_data)` and see if you get `NaN`

Comment: Are you validating or tolerating?   Do you want to reject `4'd2'` or strip out the invalid characters to make `42`?   (Confused by what "replace invalid inputs with an empty string" meant)

Comment: My requirements for the validation are more complex. I just need to solve one piece of the puzzle for now. That's why I'm messing with strings and regexes. But Aaron's solution is sufficient for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the following :

```
(?:[^0-9\.\-]|\.{2,}|-{2,})+
```

It matches either characters that aren't digits nor `.`or `-`, or sequences of two or more `.` or `-`.

That alternation is put inside a `(?:non-capturing group)` in order to repeat it with the quantifier `+` without creating an useless capturing group.

Note that you don't have to escape `.` in a character class nor the `-` at the first or last position of a character class : `(?:[^0-9.-]|\.{2,}|-{2,})+` should work just as well.

[Regex101 sample](https://regex101.com/r/IeMaTt/2).